# AddCommandLine not found .netcore 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, .net-standard-2.0

While i'm trying to invoke AddCommandLine() function on ConfigurationBuilder am getting syntax error that specifying

- IConfigurationBuilder doesn't a definition or doesnot contain an extension method AddCommandLine accepting the first argument as IConfigurationBuilder

Project was of .NetStandard 2.0

Environment:

- .net core 2.1
- .net Standard 2.0
- OS : window 10

code snippet :

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();
```

**Note: Tried to use ConfigurationBuilder from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration**

Comment: Looks like you need this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine/.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks @KirkLarkin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When getting the following error:

```
'IConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddCommandLine' and no extension method 'AddCommandLine' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationBuilder'
```

Run the following on the Nuget Package Manager Console in Visual Studio

```
Install-Package -ProjectName MyProj Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine
```

Or run the following using the dotnet cli:

```
dotnet add myproj.csproj package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine
```

Reference errors for various extensions may be common when working with [GenericHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

When working with GenericHost it may be an option to add a metapackage such as:

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage for ASP.NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Documenting original [answer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine/) by [Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin)